# can't load workbook with openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, load, openpyxl

I'm trying tu use openpyxl to open excel-files with python. It already worked but suddenly it doesn't. I successfully installed openpyxl. I can import openpyxl but I am not able to use any functions of this module.

```
import openpyxl
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('sampletable.xlsx')

result: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'load_workbook'
```

second example:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
result: ImportError: cannot import name 'Workbook'
```

I am using openpyxl 2.4.0. on Python 2.7.13 interpreter
and openpyxl 2.4.7. on Python 3.4.3.

Comment: You probably have a file named `openpyxl.py` in the current working directory. Rename that and deleted `openpyxl.pyc`

Comment: Yes, that's right. Just deleted the file openpyxl.py from the current working directory and now it works! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
```

"import openpyxl" does not seem to work for loading existing workbooks.

Answer (score 0):

**you must import load_workbook**

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb=load_workbook("sampletable.xlsx")
```