# How to display openpyxl version via code in pycharm 2020.1.1 (python 3.8)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

I barely understand anything from the error console. There is more errors than the code has lines :-(

I'm using this resource to learn about openpyxl library. I have version 3.0.3 installed but nothing seems to work. I can't even load file `'zest.xlsx'` that is open and active just like the excel file in the video I'm learning from.

[image]

```
import openpyxl
print(openpyxl.__version__)

wb_obj = openpyxl.load_workbook('zest.xlsx')
print(wb_obj)
```

I think the first line executes well but what happens after is a mystery to me.

Why the `print(openpyxl.__version__)` line doesn't display the version just like on the video??

https://youtu.be/q6Mc_sAPZ2Y?t=339

https://youtu.be/AOTCpZbC80Y?t=101

`print(openpyxl.version)` also doesn't work.

And what `__init__` is ??

Why the `wb_obj = openpyxl.load_workbook('zest.xlsx')` line doesn't load the file that is already open??

[image]

I've also read this threads looking for the answers:

[Openpyxl not found in Pycharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49413493/openpyxl-not-found-in-pycharm)

[can't load workbook with openpyxl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44007451/cant-load-workbook-with-openpyxl)

[image: These are the filenames in my project directory.]

I've also read this comment: "You probably have a file named `openpyxl.py` in the current working directory. Rename that and deleted `openpyxl.pyc` by user `mechanical_meat`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, I am guessing as I do some same stuff here but your XLSX file needs to reside in the same folder as the .py file (in pycharm it is the project folder and I do not see the file in your screenshot there).
I always look at the last line of the error message that tells you the first issue the interpreter encountered.